# Why am I running into this simple If loop error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So , the compiler returns a syntax error for my if loop in this code, I am very new to Python any & all help will greatly be appreciated.

```
    enter code lower_number = int(input('Enter the lower number'))
higher_number = int(input('Enter the higher number'))
r = random.randint(higher_number,last_number)

print("you have got only ", round(math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2)) ," chances")
 
count = 0
while count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2)  :
                                  count = count + 1
guess = int(input("Type your guess here")
    
#the next line is the line that returns the error
 if r == guess : 
print("wow you genius")
                    break;
elif guess < x :
        print("not high enough")
elif guess > x :
        print("too high ")
                                  
if count > math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
            print("sorry, try next time")
```

Comment: Please always post full stack trace with questions regarding errors.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of indentation errors, but can't know if this is due to copying problems or if it actually happens for you.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gulzar correctly suggested, you have several indentation errors and your code is not complete, so it's difficult for us to reproduce your use case.

Nevertheless this might help you:

```
count = 0
while count < math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2)  :
    count = count + 1
    guess = int(input("Type your guess here"))
        
    #the next line is the line that returns the error
    if r == guess : 
        print("wow you genius")
        break
    elif guess < x :
        print("not high enough")
    elif guess > x :
        print("too high ")
                                      
    if count > math.log(upper - lower + 1, 2):
        print("sorry, try next time")
```

The problems in your *while* loop were:

- indentation (pay attention, it is fundamental in python)
- a missing parenthesis in the line `guess = int(input("Type your guess here"))`

Comment: Works perfectly, the error i made was the onw with the missing parenthesis, thanks a lot for pointing this out :)